# Not able to click on Hamburger menu

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android, hamburger-menu

`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_gradient"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NavigationTheme"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/logoimg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

`[image: Here is the Appium screenshot to find layout element ids.]I am trying to test android app which contains hamburger menu using Appium. I tried with find by Xpath, id, accessibilityId & className. All are not working.

This is how I am initialising driver.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capability);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Open navigation drawer").click();
driver.findElementById("Open navigation drawer").click();
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Open navigation drawer']").click();
driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ImageButton").click();
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think then name of the burger icon is "Ok". Not sure if both are caps or none of them are. But try this

Comment: While screenshots of code are usually frowned-upon here, this would be an exception. Please add a screenshot of the UIAutomator screen with the element highlighted so we can see the properties and better answer your question.

Comment: @Janwilx72 its not working dude.

Comment: @BillHileman Now I have added screenshot and xml layout.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like you are using at least one, maybe two correct locators.  Since they do not work, it would be helpful to see how you are instantiating your driver.  Please add that code to your original post as well.

Comment: @BillHileman Now I have added that code.

Comment: Your initialization also looks correct to me.  Sorry, I see no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you @BillHileman for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

If you could post the source code for the element you're trying to find and click on, it'd be helpful. However, I can make some guesses.

1. `driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ImageButton");` Did you forget `.click()` here?
2. `driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Open navigation drawer").click();`
   `driver.findElementById("Open navigation drawer").click();`

   Are you sure `Open navigation drawer` is the ID of this element. It seems be the value of the `content-desc` attribute according to `driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Open navigation drawer']").click();`

According to http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/, you should avoid XPath selection due to performance issues.

Double check that you've got the correct `ID` and `Accessibility ID`; and you're not making the mistake as described above.

Comment: 1) Sorry. I have added click() now. 2) We couldn't able to find id for that hamburger menu button. I think its default button from NavigationDrawer. "Open navigation drawer" might be the content description. We have found Accessibility ID by using Appium desktop tool. We couldn't able to find "ID".

Comment: @Che Does it work now after you've added `.click()` to the last statement?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, its not working even adding that click().

Comment: @Che Would you be able to add source code as suggested? I suspect the hamburger button is not an `android.widget.ImageButton` but an `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle ` instead.

Comment: Now I have added screenshot and xml layout. Please look into that.